# Convert a file into a downloadable file in url - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, url, server, upload

Is it possible to upload a file who is locally stored in our computer, in a server, and have a final url to download it ?

**Like this exemple (*this is an excel file*) :**

http://mapa.aji-france.com/mapa/file/marche/18143/DPGF%20VIERGE%20URUGUAY%20LABORATOIRES%20H174-H176-BUANDERIE.xls

I need to do this because i'm using an API (who do a excel preview with a .xls file on a web page), and we need to have the url of the file..

Answer (score 0):

You need some server-side mechanism to handle the uploaded file (e.g. a PHP script or a servlet or whatnot). You cannot directly access the server file system with Javascript, as Javascript runs locally in the user's browser. So just create a simple server side script that stores the uploaded file and returns the server side file location.

Comment: Can you explain with some code please ? i don't really did a lot of php so.. @TheCoprolal

Comment: Before starting to develop web applications I think it is mandatory to get an understanding of how the browser and the server communicate via the HTTP protocol and how client side and server side code complement each other. So I think going through a beginner tutorial on web application development is the way to go. Then you will run into fewer one way streets along the journey.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do more research around this until you can attempt it. Heres a quick overview using PHP, I know you specified Javascript but PHP is very good at this.

You would have to create two files, a html file where you can upload the file from graphically, and a PHP file to take that file and put it on the server.

The HTML:

```
<form hidden action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" class="ui button">
    <input type="submit" value="upload" name="submit" class="ui primary button">
</form>
```

The php `upload.php`:

```
<?php
   $target_file = "where/to/upload/remotely" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file) or die ("failed");
?>
```

You should store both these files in your public html directory, usually `/var/www/html` on unix. The PHP file needs permissions that allow it to be executed. Theres a bit of configuration to this which would be hard to explain online, this is just showing you a very simple abstraction of how it would work.

On submission of the html form, so on submit button clicked, `upload.php` is executed (as its the action of the form), this gets the filename and moves it onto the specified directory on the server.

Then assuming the upload was successful the remote file name would be the same as the files original name. So say I uploaded `hello.txt` to `thisserver.net`, the remote path would be `thisserver.net/hello.txt`

This code assumes you have a webserver installed, such as [apache2](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html). It also assumes you have php configured to work with said webserver.

Read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_file_upload.asp) for more information.